# Why does closed questions not appear on the highest voted page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, closed-questions

One of my favorite past times include browsing through questions with the highest votes. They often give me valuable information and insights which I normally wouldn't come across.

[Take this question from Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/92862/im-a-manager-how-can-i-improve-work-relationships-and-communication-with-progr) for example. It's one of the highest voted questions yet it doesn't appear when I sort the questions by votes. I accidentally discovered that question while randomly browsing through the site, but I'm wondering how many questions I haven't been able to find because they are closed.

Now I'm sure the question has been closed for a very good reason but such questions have valuable content to many users.

What is the reason for hiding closed questions from the highest voted list? Is there an option to include them? Can StackExchange consider including such option?

Comment: That's a bit odd, if I go to the second page I can see some closed ones so not sure if it's just the first page?

Comment: Weird.. so maybe this is a bug? It seems very strange that questions would be filtered out from just the front page

Comment: Historical lock prevents questions from appearing in those lists.